# AutoFac DbContext issue - cannot be used while the model is creating

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, servicestack, autofac

I'm having a few issues getting started with AutoFac and IoC. We've got a working application however, I'm starting from scratch with this one and can't see where the differences between the two are.

I am testing this with a simple AJAX page which is calling the Service layer via a ServiceStack API. When using MockRepositories this works fine so I know that side of things is working.

However when I replace the mocks with ones that use Entity Framework, although all the registrations appear to be correct and working, I get the error "The context cannot be used while the model is being created."

I have included my code below:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}



public class IoCExampleContext : DbContext, IIoCExampleContext
{

    public IDbSet<SomeObject> SomeObjects { get; set; }

    static IoCExampleContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new IoCExampleDatabaseInitilizer());
    }

    public IoCExampleContext(string connectionStringName)
        : base(connectionStringName)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public IoCExampleContext()
        : this("name=IoCExample")
    {}


    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return Database.Connection.ConnectionString; }
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        BuildModels(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void BuildModels(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        var typeToUse = typeof(SomeObjectModelBuilder);
        var namespaceToUse = typeToUse.Namespace;

        var toReg = Assembly
                        .GetAssembly(typeToUse)
                        .GetTypes()
                        .Where(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.StartsWith(namespaceToUse))
                        .Where(type => type.BaseType.IsGenericType && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));

        foreach (object configurationInstance in toReg.Select(Activator.CreateInstance))
        {
            builder.Configurations.Add((dynamic)configurationInstance);
        }
    }
}



public class IoCExampleDatabaseInitilizer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<IoCExampleContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(IoCExampleContext context)
    {
    }
}



public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery();
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Where(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

    // ...Various "standard" CRUD calls
}



public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery()
    {
        return _dbSet;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return GetQuery().AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Where(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return GetQuery().Where(predicate);
    }

    // ...Various "standard" CRUD calls

    public void Dispose()
    {
        OnDispose(true);
    }

    protected void OnDispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
                _context = null;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class DependencyBootstrapper
{
    private ContainerBuilder _builder;

    public IContainer Start()
    {
        _builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        _builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
        RegisterControllers();
        return _builder.Build();
    }

    private void RegisterControllers()
    {
        RegisterAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        _builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

        RegisterPerLifetimeConnections();
        RegisterRepositories();
        RegisterServices();
    }

    private void RegisterAssembly(Assembly assembly)
    {
        _builder.RegisterModelBinders(assembly);
        _builder.RegisterControllers(assembly);
    }

    private void RegisterRepositories()
    {
        _builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)); 
        _builder.RegisterType<GenericRepository<SomeObject>>().As<IRepository<SomeObject>>();
        //... More registrations
    }

    private void RegisterServices()
    {
        _builder.RegisterType<SomeObjectService>().As<ISomeObjectService>();
        //... More registrations
    }

    private void RegisterPerLifetimeConnections()
    {
        const string connectionStringName = "IoCExample";
        _builder.RegisterType<IoCExampleContext>()
            .As<DbContext>()
            .WithParameter("connectionStringName", connectionStringName)
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        _builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
            .As<HttpContextBase>();
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's relevant but as we can't get access to the global.asax methods we're calling the bootstrapper through `PreApplicationStartMethod.OnPreApplicationStart` (which as far as I am aware, is pretty much the same thing as Application_Start).

What's a little concerning is that when I enable Multiple Active Result Sets on the connection string it works -which would suggest to me that I'm registering the DbContext incorrectly and it's spanning multiple contexts.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did u find any way out ?

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is the issue. Ensure you've set it up correctly in your web/app.comfig.